# Selection sort not working with certain inputs... (or not displaying it correctly)

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I wrote a function that takes two lists, Fahrenheit values and Celsius Values. I used a selection sort method that should sort the values from least to greatest. The possible Fahr Values are between and including -150 and 350 (I wrote a function to make sure input is within those numbers). When I type the following inputs: (30, 60, 10, -523235, -22, 30) it disregards the -523235 as it should but the output is: (10, 30, 60, -22, 30) which is not correct. It sorts only the first 3 numbers but once a negative is typed it doesn't sort that... I'm confused.

(The celsius values were generated by another function I wrote to convert the Fahr values to Cels values but that doesn't matter for this question)

```
def selection_sort_Fahr_Cels(temp_values_Fahr, temp_values_Cels):
    for i in range(0, len(temp_values_Fahr)):
        minIndex = i
        for val in range(i+1, len(temp_values_Fahr)):
            if temp_values_Fahr[val] < temp_values_Fahr[i]:
                minIndex = val

            if minIndex != i:
                temp_values_Fahr[i], temp_values_Fahr[minIndex] = temp_values_Fahr[minIndex], temp_values_Fahr[i]

    for i in range(0, len(temp_values_Cels)):
        minIndex = i
        for val in range(i+1, len(temp_values_Cels)):
            if temp_values_Cels[val] < temp_values_Cels[i]:
                minIndex = val

            if minIndex != i:
                temp_values_Cels[i], temp_values_Cels[minIndex] = temp_values_Cels[minIndex], temp_values_Cels[i]    

    print("                   ", "  Fahr ","     ", "  Cels ")
    print("                   ", "=======","     ", "=======")
    for i in range(len(temp_values_Fahr)):
        print("                   ","{0: 6}{1:14.1f}".format(temp_values_Fahr[i], temp_values_Cels[i]))

    print("                   ", "=======","     ", "=======")
```

The entire program is over 100 lines, I can post a link to the entire program if needed.

Update: I can not use any library functions as to sort.

Comment: https://ideone.com/GyYQIQ               <--- that is the link to the full program, it is unfinished and is written like that because I intended it that way. It is meant to have multiple functions even if they are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

you don't really want to use all that complicated code to remove illegal values and sort them. There's a more pythonic way (I only did the Fahr values):

```
def selection_sort_Fahr_Cels(temp_values_Fahr, temp_values_Cels):
    temp_values_Fahr[:] = sorted(filter(lambda x: x < 350 and x >= -150, temp_values_Fahr))

farh=[30, 60, 10, -523235, -22, 30]
selection_sort_Fahr_Cels(farh,[])
print(farh)
```

result (list is modified in-place):

```
[-22, 10, 30, 30, 60]
```

the code is using `filter` method using your criteria, and the result is passed to the `sorted` method that takes an iterable and creates a list out of it.

Not to mention that python `sorted` method is way more efficient than bubble sort.

Comment: I would need to write a separate function for the filter. I need to use, the get_temperatures function essentially or something like that, to remove illegal values. Your method is noted however and thank you for that. I should have noted before that I can't use any library functions.

Comment: Also, isn't the method that I showed, selection sort? I might be confused..

Answer (score 0):

```
def selectionsort( aList ):
    for i in range( len( aList ) ):
        least = i
        for k in range( i + 1 , len( aList ) ):
            if aList[k] < aList[least]:
                least = k

        swap( aList, least, i )
    print(aList) 


def swap( A, x, y ):
    tmp = A[x]
    A[x] = A[y]
    A[y] = tmp



selectionsort(aList)
```

I found a better selection sort method. I noticed that before, I didn't have any swap method going on.

Comment: There's no need to swap using a temp in Python. `A[x], A[y] = `A[y], A[x]`  does the same thing as `swap(A, x, y)`. Your code in this answer looks a lot neater than the code in the question, but it's mostly just that you're using shorter variable names.